# How do I put this filter in a tkinter window?

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter

I need to put this filter but I don't know if it can be applied to pandastable, because I don't know how to apply it using tkinter

This is the filter:

```
import pandas as pd

ruta = "C:\\Users\\Windows 10 Pro\\Desktop\\curso\\"

df = pd.read_excel(ruta + "libro1.xlsx")

print(df)

tipo = input("De que  tipo es? ")
alto = float(input("Cual es el alto? "))
ancho = float(input("Cual es el ancho? "))
espesor = int(input("Cual es el espesor? "))

print(df[(df['Tipo']== tipo)&(df["Alto"]>= alto + 0.15)&(df["Ancho"]>= ancho + 0.15)&(df["Espesor"]== espesor)])
```

This is what I have to display the dataframe

```
import tkinter as tk
import pandas as pd
from pandastable import Table, TableModel

class DataFrameTable(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, df=pd.DataFrame()):
        super().__init__()
        self.parent = parent
        self.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
        self.table = Table(
            self, dataframe=df,
            showtoolbar=False,
            showstatusbar=True,
            editable=False)
        self.table.show()



root = tk.Tk()
table = DataFrameTable(root, df)
root.mainloop()
```

And this would be what is in the dataframe

```
   Lote      Tipo  Alto  Ancho  Espesor
0     1     Claro  0.60    1.2        3
1     2    Espejo  0.70    1.5        4
2     3  Laminado  0.40    1.7        5
3     4     Claro  0.25    1.9        6
4     5    Espejo  0.80    1.5        7
5     6     Claro  1.20    1.3        3
```

If anyone could help me I would appreciate it very much.